# variable substitution github actions for Angular config.json

Tags: angular, github-actions

I have created an Angular app that uses `RuntimeConfigLoaderService` this service uses a `config.json` file which I want to update when I deploy my application.

I have created a deployment using github actions, the Action runs and shows the values were changed but when I open the app and display them they are empty

[image: github message]
[image: difference between values shown locally and after deployment].

Looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/github-variable-substitution), I seem to be doing the right thing, what am I missing:

**Build file**

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
        with:
          files: './ClientApp/RetroArcadeMachines/src/assets/config.json'
        env:
          read_api_url: 'https://myReadUrl'
          write_api_url: 'https://myWriteUrl'
          write_api_url_auth: 'https://myWriteUrlAuth'
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ASHY_ISLAND_0772CDD03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "./ClientApp/RetroArcadeMachines/" # App source code path
          output_location: "dist/RetroArcadeMachines" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ASHY_ISLAND_0772CDD03 }}
          action: "close"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had `isDevMode()` check in AppModule. I altered that to `environment.production` and everything work as expected

Answer (score 0):

your config.json file might be being replaced just fine, the issue is you have to load your file at runtime. you can't use angulars native observable http query methods. use Promise. this article explains in detail how to read configuration files at runtime.
https://imran3.medium.com/runtime-configuration-for-angular-c9d9082e1de3